# How to achieve a vibrant selection state in a Notification Center Today Widget

Tags: ios, ios8-today-widget, uivisualeffectview

[image]

I want to achieve a selected state with an effect similar to what the built-in widgets have, where the colors behind the notification show through. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a `UIButton` to the contentView of a `UIVisualEffectsView` using `[UIVibrancyEffect notificationCenterVibrancyEffect]`:

```
UIButton *myButton = ...
self.effectsView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:[UIVibrancyEffect notificationCenterVibrancyEffect]];
self.effectsView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self addSubview:self.effectsView];

[self.effectsView.contentView addSubview:myButton];
```

By default, your button's backgroundColor should be [UIColor clearColor]. Then, when it's tapped, just set its background color to `[[UIColor lightGrayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5]`. (The alpha value helps when content behind the notification center is almost all white).